# Welcome message after creating a mailbox user in zimbra

Tags: linux, zimbra

We have deployed a zimbra mail server of version 5.0.x. I'm trying to setting up a automatic sending welcome message when email box is created. Is there any feature or that can be done.

Can anyone please help to do it..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating the user through the interface, or using the back-end tools,or SOAP?

Comment: Using Admin User Interface and also I know that we can do it using back-end tools like zmmailbox, But that's not comfortable to my client so looking for good feature that can be added to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the relevant bug report](http://bugzilla.zimbra.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15496), this is doable with a script. But they don't say how. I'd recommend asking there